# NuxtJS ) Please let me know why 'created' is not working

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I entered `console.log('created test')` in `created` life cycle hook as follows, but nothing logs in the console window.

**Code :**

```js
<template>
  <div>
      <h1>메인 페이지</h1>
      <p>메인 페이지입니다</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  created(){
    console.log('created test');
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

**Screenshot :**

[image]

Comment: Hey, I tried it in a sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-sun-oobn74?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:0-233) and it looks like it works. Are there any other errors? How was the project created? Does this happen in every component? In general provide as much info as you can, please.

Comment: It's not Vue, It's Nuxt.js

I created the project as follows.
```npm init nuxt-app nuxt-test ```

And I added the following settings to the 'eslintrc.js' file. Can this be a problem?

// eslintrc.js
```
...
 rules: {
    'vue/multi-word-component-names': 'off',
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
  },
```

Comment: I solved the problem.
First of all, the 'NuxtLink' and '<Nuxt/>' parts that set 'router' were incorrect.

In addition, it can be seen that Nuxt recommends 'async Data' more than 'create life cycle'.